# In Magento 2 Rest Api, status codes how to use?

Tags: magento2, rest-api, messages

I would like to `return json responseobject via a status codes and messages` for the creating customer account using  magento2 REST API.

I found some documentations below:-

1) https://restfulapi.net/http-status-codes/

2) http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/get-started/gs-web-api-response.html

**API Url:-** rest/V1/customer/signup

**Method:-** POST

**Screenshot:-** http://prntscr.com/ho6moe

**Model code:-**

```
<?php


namespace Test\Custom\Model;
class CustomerSignupAccount implements \Test\Custom\Api\CustomerSignupInterface
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory
     */
    protected $customerFactory;


     /**
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory    $customerFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory
    ) {
        $this->storeManager     = $storeManager;
        $this->customerFactory  = $customerFactory;

    }


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
    */ 

     public function customerSignup($customerData)
     {  
        // Perparing Customer Data
        $firstName      = $customerData['firstname'];       
        $lastName       = $customerData['lastname'];
        $email          = $customerData['email'];


        // Validate Customer EmailAddress
        if(!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($customerData['email']), 'NotEmpty')) 
        {                              
            return 'Please check your email, it should not empty';
        }
        if(!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($customerData['email']), 'EmailAddress'))
        {
            return 'Please check your email formate and try again';
        }           

        try{

            // Get Website ID
            $websiteId  = $this->storeManager->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId();            
            $customerData = $this->customerFactory->create(); 
            $customerData->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
            $customerData->loadByEmail($email);
            if($customerData->getId())
            {
                return 'Customer account has been already registered with this email '.$email ;

            }else
            {
                //Instantiate object (this is the most important part)
                $customer   = $this->customerFactory->create();
                $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
                // Preparing data for new customer
                $customer->setEmail($email); 
                $customer->setFirstname($firstName);
                $customer->setLastname($lastName);                      
                // Save customer data
                $customer->save();

                return 'Your account has been created successfully.';
            }


        }
        catch(\Exception $e){

            return 'Something bad happend please try again';
        }

    }

}
```

Note:- Here i am able to create an account it's working fine.

Please suggest me how to  show response in the form of status codes and messages?

thanks